How do Bible scholars interpret 1 Tim 3:2 in so far as it relates to the marital status of a Bishop?
We hear St Paul exhorting in 1 Timothy 3:2 (KJV):

The bishop then must be blameless, the husband of one wife, vigilant, sober, of good behavior, given to hospitality, apt at teaching;

Some versions use the phrase ' should be faithful to his wife' in lieu of ' husband of one wife' .
A layman generally tends to interpret the phrase ' husband of one wife ' to mean that polygamy was permitted among Jews and early Christians at least in exceptional cases like the first wife  not being able to conceive(as in the case of Abraham and Hagar), but that the Bishop should not marry for a second time even if he had no children from his existing wife.
Another interpretation is that clergy below the level of Bishop were permitted to marry , but if one gets elevated as Bishop, he should not marry thereafter .Some Orthodox Syrian Christian groups of Southern India follow the latter ideology. But, in Catholicism,  clergy at any level of hierarchy are not permitted to marry. But it is implied that celibacy of   priests was not insisted on in the early days of Catholic Church.
My question therefore, is : How do Bible scholars interpret 1 Tim 3:2 in so far as it relates to the marital status of a Bishop ?

as the OP is apparently aware there are various understandings of this verse. This may be a case where the question strays over the dreaded "opinion-based" line. This link provides many scholarly views.

Thanks, Dan Fefferman. I would not expect the scholars to be of one single view ! Could you give a summary of different views topped up with your personal view ?

First, the translation "bishop" is most unfortunate for modern English.  The pertinent word here is ἐπίσκοπος (episkopos) = "overseer" derived from ἐπί (epi, "over") and σκοπός (skopos, "watcher" or "guardian") (Strong's).
In the NT church there were no "levels" of bishops, etc, just an elected overseer or elder for each church.
The New Testament had two types of officers: those appointed by the Holy Spirit (prophets, apostles, miracle workers, etc, 1 Cor 12) and those elected: elders/overseers and deacons (1 Tim 3:1-13).  The fact that the New Testament sanctions neither a formal priesthood nor management structure, does not preclude the election of some offices to administrative functions.  However, the only officers discussed in the New Testament are elders/overseers and deacons.  Further, only elders are recorded as being formally appointed by the process of election (Acts 14:23, 2 Cor 8:19, “cheirotoneo” – “to elect by raising the hand”).  One assumes that deacons were appointed in a similar fashion.
Further, there is no office of “pastor” (= Latin word for “shepherd”) that is separate from elder.  That is, the elders were to be shepherds of the flock.  1 Peter 5:1-4, Acts 20:17, 28.
Thus, the early church was a very simple, local congregational (informal) organization without any visible super-structure.  The congregations were bound together, not by an institution, but by a common purpose to “make disciples” (Matt 28:19), with Jesus as the “Chief Shepherd” (1 Peter 5:4).  Elders were to serve and imitate the Chief Shepherd (1 Peter 5:1-4).
Thus, 1 Tim 3:2 requires of a local church overseer is the following:

above reproach
monogamous
temperate/sober
self-controlled
respectable
hospitable
able to teach.

Subsequent verses add further requirements.

When one consider the role of Timothy in appointing these elders, one must concede the similarities between his role and the role of the modern day bishop.

@JamesAjiduah - perhaps but that is reading something back into the text that is not there.  Timothy is not given such a title.

One can easily argue that the Trinity is not in Scripture because of this term fallacy. Concepts must be in Scripture, not terms.

There's very good reason to see this as a limit on marriages, i.e., that a bishop/deacon must only be married once.
Chapter 5 tells us why:

Do not rebuke an older man harshly, but exhort him as if he were your father. Treat younger men as brothers, 2 older women as mothers, and younger women as sisters, with absolute purity.

This is to Timothy, but by extension to the others under his oversight. The last command would be hard to put into practice for an elder looking for a second marriage. Similar language to 1 Timothy 3 occurs in the qualifications for the order of widows

A widow is to be put on the list only if she is not less than sixty years old, having been the wife of one man, 10 having a reputation for good works; and if she has brought up children, if she has shown hospitality to strangers, if she has washed the saints’ feet, if she has assisted those in distress, and if she has devoted herself to every good work. 11 But refuse to register younger widows, for when they feel physical desires alienating them from Christ, they want to get married, 12 thereby incurring condemnation, because they have ignored their previous pledge

One of the requirements to be enrolled as a widow is to be the wife of one man and be 60 and older. The explanation for prohibiting women younger from being on the widow list negates remarriage as a possibility.

Short answer:
A church leader (to use a neutral term) is required to be of good character. Such a character is defined by a list of qualities, including "husband of one wife". In context, it is most reasonable to interpret this the same way as the other items on the list. Therefore, we are not talking about a marriage requirement (which both Jesus and Paul would have failed) but a character requirement: if the leader is married, it must be a healthy marriage.
The detail:
The context here is Paul's advice to Timothy about appointing local church leaders. He says:

1 Timothy 3:2-10 NIV
Now the overseer is to be above reproach, faithful to his wife, temperate, self-controlled, respectable, hospitable, able to teach, 3 not given to drunkenness, not violent but gentle, not quarrelsome, not a lover of money. 4 He must manage his own family well and see that his children obey him, and he must do so in a manner worthy of full[a] respect. 5 (If anyone does not know how to manage his own family, how can he take care of God’s church?) 6 He must not be a recent convert, or he may become conceited and fall under the same judgment as the devil. 7 He must also have a good reputation with outsiders, so that he will not fall into disgrace and into the devil’s trap.
In the same way, deacons[b] are to be worthy of respect, sincere, not indulging in much wine, and not pursuing dishonest gain. 9 They must keep hold of the deep truths of the faith with a clear conscience. 10 They must first be tested; and then if there is nothing against them, let them serve as deacons.

Now it's worth noting that this is a list. Furthermore, it's an illustrative list. It is not comprehensive. We can see this in two ways.
On the one hand, we can consider what is not included in the list. For example, there is no mention of prayer. Yet who would deduce from this that Paul is saying a church leader doesn't need to pray?
On the other hand, we can compare the lists for "overseers" and "deacons". (I'm using the NIV terms here.) It's clear that the two lists cover the same general categories. Drunkenness, maturity, respect, not money hungry: these are all found in both sets. And yet the phrasing is not identical. Paul is not hung up on precise words, but on general principles. Also, despite these parallels, some items are not found in both lists. Only the overseer is barred from being violent. Do we really think this gives the deacon permission to be violent?
A comparative example:
The importance of this is that when it comes to interpreting a list, the key principle is that we take from the list whatever meaning applies to all the items on the list together. Consider this (fictional) example from a very different area: tax law. Imagine a new tax, to be charged on imported goods. One sentence defines the scope of the tax:

This tax shall be charged on all imported goods.

Here it's reasonable to interpret "all" as meaning literally "all". Everything imported is charged the tax.
But now imagine the sentence says:

This tax shall be applied to cars, trucks, vans, motorbikes and all other imports.

Now the word "all" has a different meaning. It is a principle of legal interpretation that the last general term must be understood to have the same meaning as the other items on the list. And here the list is various types of vehicles. So an imported minibus is not on the list, but will probably incur the tax. But imported clothing is a different category, and therefore will not be taxed.
Back to 1 Timothy
In Paul's first list, we find the following characteristics of a good overseer:

above reproach
a marriage item (which we will come back to)
temperate
self-controlled
respectable
hospitable
able to teach
not given to drunkenness
not violent but gentle
not quarrelsome
not a lover of money
a respected manager of his family
not a recent convert
having a good reputation with outsiders

Now, how does marriage fit into this list? Surely the clear point being made is that this is not about status, but about quality of life and behaviour. We are talking here about judging the character of a leader by his behaviour. If outwardly we see a man being gentle, self controlled and generous with his money, we have clues to his inner character. If outsiders speak well of him, then again, we learn something about his character. So surely we should interpret the marriage clause in the same way.
Literally Paul says the overseer should be μιᾶς γυναικὸς ἄνδρα, a one-woman man. Now technically, this is ambiguous. It could be about status: He must be married to one woman (Thus restricting leadership to those who are married, or possibly ruling out people who are divorced or remarried). But it could be about character: He must be focussed only on one woman, namely his wife.
The KJV in the original post follows the first interpretation: "The husband of one wife." The NIV follows the second interpretation, that this is all about character: He must be "faithful to his wife." In my view, given the strong direction of every other item on the list, the NIV translation is the right one. Paul is not saying that an overseer must be married. He's saying that if he is married, he must be a husband of good character.

EDIT
(This edit is a response to the points made by James Adijuah in his answer and comment.)
Another answer draws on verses from 1 Timothy 5 to argue that Paul is giving rules that limit remarriage. But these verses have been misunderstood:

(1 Timothy 5:2-3, NIV)
Do not rebuke an older man harshly, but exhort him as if he were your father. Treat younger men as brothers, 2 older women as mothers, and younger women as sisters, with absolute purity.

James' argument is that "the last command would be hard to put into practice for an elder looking for a second marriage." But this passage has nothing to do with marriage at all. If Paul wanted to give instructions about marriage or remarriage, he has the ability to talk directly on the subject (see for example 1 Corinthians 7). Here he is simply talking about general relationships within the church. In effect Paul is saying, "Timothy, no matter who you minister to, young or old, man or woman, let that ministry be filled with purity. Love the people of your flock as if they were members of your own family."

(1 Timothy 5:9-12 NIV)
A widow is to be put on the list only if she is not less than sixty years old, having been the wife of one man, 10 having a reputation for good works; and if she has brought up children, if she has shown hospitality to strangers, if she has washed the saints’ feet, if she has assisted those in distress, and if she has devoted herself to every good work. 11 But refuse to register younger widows, for when they feel physical desires alienating them from Christ, they want to get married, 12 thereby incurring condemnation, because they have ignored their previous pledge

James states:
One of the requirements to be enrolled as a widow is to be the wife of one man and be 60 and older. The explanation for prohibiting women younger from being on the widow list negates remarriage as a possibility.

First, James is right that a parallel expression appears both here and in chapter 3. The overseer must be μιᾶς γυναικὸς ἄνδρα, a "one-woman man" (1 Timothy 3.2). In the same way a widow on the church welfare list must be ἑνὸς ἀνδρὸς γυνή, a "one-man woman" (1 Timothy 5:9).

however, this doesn't resolve the main question, because in both cases we still need to interpret the phrase. And I would argue that in the case of widows we are again talking about character. The widow is to be a "one-man woman," known for her good deeds (which Paul again illustrates with a list). So in my view the reasons why "faithful in marriage" was a good translation for overseers are also good reasons for translating it that way for widows.

James quotes 1 Timothy 5:11-12 about younger widows: They should not register because their desires may lead them to want (re)marriage. This is admittedly a difficult passage to interpret, but there is one thing it cannot mean. It cannot mean that Paul was ruling against remarriage. Because in the same instructions, that is precisely what he advises:



(1 Timothy 5.14 NIV)
So I counsel younger widows to marry, to have children, to manage their homes and to give the enemy no opportunity for slander.


Therefore I think the best understanding of this passage is this: Paul is giving general instructions about the support the church should give widows. For older widows of good standing, support is the right thing to do (sometimes from the church, sometimes from the widow's family). For younger widows, remarriage is a good option, because that will prevent them from getting into trouble through their natural passions. They will avoid the shame of signing up to the widows' list and then breaking their "first pledge" (to God? to the church?)

It's worth noting that Paul's advice is very similar in 1 Corinthians 7. He would personally prefer men and women not to get married, because "the time is short" and because marriage creates a divided focus: both God and one's partner. But he immediately stresses that if the couple are "burning with passion", they should get married, and there is no shame in that choice.



When similar language is used in 1 Timothy 5, remarriage is prohibited for the parties. There's reason for the RSV translation of "married only once."

I've just read 1 Timothy 5. I can't see anything about remarriage. You'll need to be more specific.

Ah, I've just read your answer. I disagree with your interpretation, and when I have time I will edit my answer to cover your points.

Paul's comments in those who qualify for the widow list prevent remarriage as a possibility., hence why he restricts it to older women 60 and above. The text indicates those on the widow list made vows NOT to remarry.

@James, I feel like you haven't actually read my answer, because you haven't responded to the points I've made. In my judgment, you are reading your ideas into the text, when they are simply not there. But I suspect we will have to agree to differ.

What is the pledge widows make?

Paul doesn't say, so I think we need to be humble and cautious here. My provisional answer is that it's a pledge to Christ. In other words, Paul is warning against passions that distract us from our first devotion to Jesus and the Christian faith. But as I said in my answer, there's one thing it cannot mean. It cannot be a pledge to not remarry, because in the very next sentence Paul advises such widows to manage those passions by doing precisely that: to remarry.

Not even the text agrees with you: "refuse to register younger widows, for when they feel physical desires alienating them from Christ, they want to get married, 12 thereby incurring condemnation, because they have ignored their previous pledge." Younger widows WERE to remarry.

I agree with that. Which for me means that a general rule against remarriage simply didn't exist. Are we talking past each other?

We were discussing the widow list. The context heavily implies the criteria for being on said list was a pledge NOT to remarry, which is why the age requirement is emphasized

Well as I said we will probably have to agree to differ. I think the context clearly shows that (1) Paul had no problem with the general idea of a widow remarrying, in fact encouraged it where appropriate. Therefore (2) the pledge (which is not specified therefore needs to be interpreted) must be talking about something else. As to the age of 60, I don't see that as a fixed rule (it would go against Paul's emphasis elsewhere on "life in the Spirit".) It's just a recognition that older women are less likely in the real world to remarry and therefore more likely to need church support.
